# M2M communication via HTTPS - How to authenticate?

Tags: php, authentication, m2m

**Requirements**

I'm currently working on a PHP portal for a machine-seller. His machines are capable of communicating over the internet with an integrated SBC with LAN port. The consumers who bought a machine can configure it online after they logged in to the machine-sellers-portal.

After they configured it online, they can download the configuration file via the HMI (touch display at the machine itself) to the machine. The configuration file contains valuable and private information.
The HMI is not browser based. It's a binary application that has, for example, a button "Load config". The rest has to be done in bash/php-scripts in the backround.

**Solution for authentication?**

I'm in a very early state of conception, but I'm wondering about some processes. I've never had a machine thats needs access to my services, only humans. What is the way to do this actually?

I have three approaches:

**1. Access with "API-Key"**

Means: In the OS of the SBC lies a file containing a sequence like `8asd7d7d`. When I receive a `GET`-request to `portal.company.com/getConfig/8asd7d7d` I know from which machine it comes and that it is allowed to receive this config.

Disadvantage: The buyer has access to the SBCs file system. He could destroy the file by accident. He could find out the generating scheme and download configuration files from other buyers.

**2. Generating one-time UUID-URL**

Means: The consumer creates his configuration online. After that, he gets displayed a one-time URL like `portal.company.com/getConfig/d8ac2292ea1fec3fe5c65e6ef573` which he can enter in the HMI and load the file.

Disadvantage: The consumer has to type a long URL into the display of the HMI.

**3. Simulating the human authentication process**

Means: The machine sends a valid post-request to `portal.company.com/login` with the login-data of its human owner. It gets a session-cookie (is that even possible in a non-browser environment like pure PHP-scripts?!) and the portal logic knows which URLs are accessible and which not (like for a human visitor).

**Any other/better ideas?**

I tend to use solution 2 as it's relatively easy to implement and hopefully secure (lets pretend a sha512-string as URL-parameter). Do you have any better suggestions? Mind, that the other way round is not possible, the portal can not actively push data to the machine (as it has no fixed IP, no webserver, ...)

Answer (score 0):

If the device supports cryptographic functions, PKI can be used. Encrypt the data using the device public key. Only the device knowing the private key can decrypt the config file. PKI supports authentication also. here the device connects to  a login portal that requests client certificate and after authentication of client, the config file is send to the device encrypted in device public key.

cons: each device requires a client certifcate.

Comment: I'm actively using and understanding PKI (SSH, PGP), but authentication with certificates is new to me (not as consumer but as developer). Do you have a reading recommendation on this topic?

Comment: check this [link]http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201119/web-authentication-using-pki-certs  answer here